# Is there a way to replace the legend or axis without redrawing the whole plot?

Tags: r, plot

Sometimes I will place a legend at a particular location on the plot, let's say topright, and then I see that it covers an important part of the plot.  Is there a way I can switch it to topleft or some other place without having to run all the other commands first?  Sometimes I have the same problem with the axes, I misspell a word and then I have to issue all the commands again.

I eventually place everything in an R script which means this becomes less of a problem, but sometimes I want to quickly test something in console.  Please tell me I have overlooked a basic command that does this.

Comment: I don't think you have overlooked anything.  If you worked in grid graphics you could **in principle** modify or delete elements on the fly, but in practice you will be better off changing the way you interact with R.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions in what I should change as far as how I interact with R?  Hopefully it might help some other new users too.

Comment: As suggested by @GabrielFlorit below: choose an interface that makes it easy for you to run partial or whole scripts/chunks of R code as you are editing them.  These range from the built-in script editors in Windows and MacOS (both functional, the one in MacOS is a bit fuller-featured); to interfaces such as Notepad++, RStudio, Tinn-R (the latter now a bit rusty); to full-featured editing environments such as vim and Emacs; to development interfaces such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing, but you're on the right track - a script is definitely the way to go. I would also recommend [R Studio](http://rstudio.org/), a free R IDE, which gives you several displays, one for scripts, one for the console, one for your plots - it's great! It makes working with scripts as easy as interacting with the traditional R console.

Answer (score 1):

As Gabriel told you, a script is the best way. However, the following link could help you:

[Using Inkscape to Post-edit Labels in R Graphs](http://blog.carlislerainey.com/2011/09/26/using-inkscape-to-post-edit-labels-in-r-graphs/)